# taskdef class com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.ConverterTask cannot be found

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, javacard

i create sample project with java card development kit 2.2.1 in netbeans. 
my code like this and i follow tutorial from https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/public/research/smartcard/javacardcompilation.

```
private byte[] echoBytes;
private static final short LENGTH_ECHO_BYTES = 256;

protected TestApplet02()
{
    echoBytes = new byte[LENGTH_ECHO_BYTES];
    register();
}

public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
{
    new TestApplet02();
}

public void process(APDU apdu)
{
    byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();

    short bytesRead = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    short echoOffset = (short)0;

    while ( bytesRead > 0 ) {
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, echoBytes, echoOffset, bytesRead);
        echoOffset += bytesRead;
        bytesRead = apdu.receiveBytes(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
    }

    apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength( (short) (echoOffset + 5) );

    // echo header
    apdu.sendBytes( (short)0, (short) 5);
    // echo data
    apdu.sendBytesLong( echoBytes, (short) 0, echoOffset );
}
```

and my build.xml is here.

```
<target name="-post-init">
    <!-- Java Card Ant Tasks definition -->
    <path id="jc-tasks" >
        <pathelement path="${jctasks.path}"/>
    </path>    
    <taskdef name="convert" 
        classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.ConverterTask"
        classpathref="jc-tasks" />
    <taskdef name="verifycap" 
        classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.VerifyCapTask"
        classpathref="jc-tasks" />
    <!-- Java Card classpath -->
    <path id="jc-classpath" >
        <pathelement path="${jc.home}/lib/converter.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${jc.home}/lib/offcardverifier.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${jc.home}/lib/scriptgen.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${jc.home}/lib/apdutool.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${jc.home}/lib/apduio.jar"/>            
        <pathelement path="."/>
    </path>
</target>

<!-- Target responsible for conversion and verification of the applet -->
<target name="convert" depends="init">
    <convert
        dir="${build.classes.dir}"
        nobanner="true"            
        JCA="true"
        EXP="true"
        CAP="true"
        packagename="${jc.package.name}"
        packageaid="${jc.package.AID}"
        majorminorversion="${jc.package.version}">
        <AppletNameAID
            appletname="${jc.package.name}.${jc.applet.name}"
            aid="${jc.applet.AID}"/>

        <exportpath>
            <pathelement path="${jc.export_files}"/>
        </exportpath>            

        <classpath refid="jc-classpath"/>
    </convert>

    <verifycap Verbose="true" CapFile="${build.classes.dir}/${jc.package.path}/javacard/${jc.package.shortName}.cap">
        <exportfiles file="${jc.export_files}/java/lang/javacard/lang.exp" />
        <exportfiles file="${jc.export_files}/javacard/framework/javacard/framework.exp" />
        <exportfiles file="${jc.export_files}/javacard/security/javacard/security.exp" />
        <exportfiles file="${jc.export_files}/javacardx/crypto/javacard/crypto.exp" />
        <exportfiles file="${build.classes.dir}/${jc.package.path}/javacard/${jc.package.shortName}.exp" />
        <classpath refid="jc-classpath"/>
    </verifycap>
</target>

<!-- Overriding target, which runs conversion and verification instead of creating JAR file -->
<target name="jar" depends="init,compile,convert">
</target>

<!-- Target, which runs specific script via GPShell -->
<target name="run-script" depends="init">
    <!-- Generate and execute build script -->
    <copy file="${gpshell.templatepath}\\${gpshell.script}" todir="build//scripts" overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>
            <expandproperties/>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
    <exec executable="${gpshell.cmd}">
        <arg value="build//scripts//${gpshell.script}"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<!-- Overriding target, which runs script during testing -->
<target name="test" depends="jar,run-script">
</target>
```

i clean and build my project and i get this error: "C:\Users\BRI\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestApplet02\build.xml:81: taskdef class com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.ConverterTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]". would should i do? Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that tutorial is quite outdated. You can try a simple approach for beginners with [ant-javacard](https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard) which is a simple and understandable ant build.xml tool, which should work with any IDE.